# Show div when select-multiple field is not null

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a sidebar which is initially hidden on pageload. I want to show the div `sidebar` when the select-multiple field `stickets` isn't empty. I've been trying different solutions but so far it only works if it's a textbox where I input the value myself. What am I missing/doing wrong? Is this even possible for select-multiple?

```
$("#stickets").change(function() {
    if(this.value.replace(/\s/g, "") === "") {
       $(".sidebar").hide();
    } else {
       $(".sidebar").show();
    }
});

$(".sidebar").click(function() {
   $("#stickets").val("");
   $(this).hide();
});
```

**EDIT:** I found out that it does work but only after I select an item the field. How can I show the the div without having to do this extra step?

Comment: Add `html` to your question

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if($("#stickets").val()==''){
    $(".sidebar").hide();
}else{
 $(".sidebar").show();
}
```

Comment: Not really, with $("#stickets").val("") you are assigning to the element #stickets the value "". so your test return ever true and while changing the value of field.Completely wrong

Comment: copy paste mistakes #Madpapo

Comment: Thank you for the response. Please check edit. This works also but still does the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Not really.The select multiple return an array list when calling the jQuery.val() method.
So the correct test could be:

```
$("#stickets").change(function(){
    if (!$("#stickets").val() || !$("#stickets").val().length){
                $(".sidebar").hide();
    }else{
                $(".sidebar").show();
    }
})
```

Comment: The event listener was missing

Answer (score 0):

I have an dropdown menu and an add button which adds the selected value to the select-multiple list `stickets`. I just had to put the `$(".sec-sidebar").show();` to the function for the add button.

Thanks everyone!